# Eliminar elemento especifico AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Cuando doy en 'Borrar', siempre se eliminan los elementos de arriba a abajo, pero no aquel sobre el que doy en Borrar, es decir, el elemento concreto

```
**html:**
<tr ng-repeat="tarea in tareas">
            <td>{{tarea.titulo}}</td>
            <td>{{tarea.nombre}}</td>
            <td>{{tarea.fecha}}</td>
            <td><button type="submit">Editar</button>
            <button type="submit" ng-click="Delete(tarea)">Borrar</button>
            </td>
        </tr>

**js:**

 $scope.Delete = function (tarea) {
        $scope.tareas.splice(tarea, 1);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para eliminar un elemento dado (sin saber su posición) de un array, te recomiendo usar `filter`:

```
$scope.Delete = function (tarea) {
  $scope.tareas = $scope.tareas.filter(dato => dato != tarea);
}
```

Aunque también podrías enviar el índice, en lugar de la tarea completa, con lo que tu código funcionaría sin más cambios:

```
    <tr ng-repeat="tarea in tareas">
        <td>{{tarea.titulo}}</td>
        <td>{{tarea.nombre}}</td>
        <td>{{tarea.fecha}}</td>
        <td><button type="submit">Editar</button>
        <button type="submit" ng-click="Delete($index)">Borrar</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 4):

Creo que tenemos un error en el uso de la función `splice`. De acuerdo a la documentación, la función [Splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/splice) recibe como primer parámetro el índice desde donde debemos iniciar, pero en tu código estas pasando el objeto tarea. Esto causa que la función no funcione de la manera esperada y comience a eliminar de arriba hacia abajo. Para eliminar los registros de tu arreglo, puedes pasar la variable `$index` (incluida dentro del ciclo `ngRepeat`) a la función delete. De esta manera tenemos la posición correcta para eliminar el registro requerido.

Ejemplo:

```js
var ngApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

ngApp.controller('myController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.tareas = [
      {titulo: 'Título 1', nombre : 'Nombre 1', fecha : new Date().getTime()},
      {titulo: 'Título 2', nombre : 'Nombre 2', fecha : new Date().getTime()},
      {titulo: 'Título 3', nombre : 'Nombre 3', fecha : new Date().getTime()},
      {titulo: 'Título 4', nombre : 'Nombre 4', fecha : new Date().getTime()},

    ];
    
    $scope.delete = function (index) {
      $scope.tareas.splice(index,1);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<table ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="tarea in tareas;">
    <td>{{tarea.titulo}}</td>
    <td>{{tarea.nombre}}</td>
    <td>{{tarea.fecha}}</td>
    <td><button type="submit">Editar</button>
    <button type="submit" ng-click="delete($index)">Borrar</button>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```