# Borrar elemento de un array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Uso redux para la parte de una interfaz donde al darle a un boton debe borrar cierta "etiqueta" de una app de compras. Sin embargo al darle DELETE_ITEM no funciona correctamente. He intentando con filter, delete y, masomenos, funciona con slice donde borra todos los elementos menos el seleccionado (cosa que tiene que ser al revés).

En DELETE_ITEM llamo al id correspondiente de la etiqueta y busco su posicion en el array, pero por alguna razon no responde con filter, he intentado el "items: state.items.filter(item => item !== i)" pero no borra nada y con "==" termina borrando todo.

```
const initialState = {
    total: 0,
    items: []  }

export default (state = initialState, action) => { 
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_TO_CART:
            const item = action.item;
            item.id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1001).toString()
            
            return {
                items: state.items.concat(action.item)
            }
            
        case DELETE_ITEM: /
    
            const index = action.item;
            const i = state.items.map(items => items.id).indexOf(index);
            
            return {
               items: state.items.filter()
                
            } 
    return state;
}
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Eliminar elemento especifico AngularJS](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/333792/eliminar-elemento-especifico-angularjs). Y en realidad `filter` debería ser suficiente, puedes probar con `state.items.fitler(item => item.id != action.item)`, supongo que `action.item` representa el `id` del objeto que quieres borrar.

Comment: ¿Has probado `array.splice(index, 1)`? Eso te eliminará el elemento con el index especificado en tu `array`

Comment: @BrayanMartínezSantana. Gracias ya lo solucione. No creia que se podia directamente llamar al item.id, entonces por eso buscaba primero su posicion y luego trataba de filtrarlo pero creo eso no era eficiente